# Apache ProxyPass timeout 300 seconds, but why?

Tags: apache, proxypass

Apache HTTP Server 2.4.33 on OEL 7.x x64
I am proxying to a backend Apache Tomcat Server and everything works perfectly except for if a running transaction (this web app has a reporting feature I use) and if I choose a large report that takes over 5 minutes, it will timeout and state in the web app that connection to webserver lost.

I tried a bunch of things like connectionTimeout and timeout and Keepalive.  No matter waht I do, exactly at 300 seconds it drops.  If I hit http://appserver:80 directly and do the exact same thing, it runs for like 8 minutes and then returns my gigantic report.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    ProxyTimeout 900
    ProxyPass / http://appserver:80/ retry=1 acquire=3000 
    connectionTimeout=900 timeout=900 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://appserver:80/
```

Comment: It stops at 300 seconds?  Looks like `TimeOut 300` is set in your httpd.conf.  The "main" timeout still applies, even if the proxy times out at 900.

Comment: In addition to what @Nic3500 has said, if you can, you might want to think about a redesign of your service. It might be better to have the first call start the processing, and each sequential call can just check the status of job processing in the background. Relying on a TCP connection to complete the job might not be the best.